# Tips for sitting holding a Sefer Torah without hurting your shoulder?

Tags: how-to, torah-service, sefer-torah

I'm occasionally asked in shul to take out the second Sefer Torah, which also involves holding it until it's needed.  I usually sit holding it with one eitz chayim resting on the chair between my legs, the other eitz chayim on the other side of my left leg, the top resting on my right shoulder, and my right arm around it.  By the end of the second aliyah, my right shoulder is always sore.

I generally won't accept this kavod anymore, except on Chol Hamoed Pesach or Rosh Chodesh Chanuka, because it's too painful.

Is there a way of holding it that works better?  (I'm right handed, if it matters.)

Comment: This sounds like a question a chiropractor could answer better than me. Some ideas - Sit up straight with your back resting against the back of the chair. That gives you the best back support. Then, you can always switch shoulders about every 5 minutes. I hope you have at least taken the *keter* (crown) and other ornaments off the Torah before you sit. Those thing scan add about an extra 10 lbs. of weight! In the worst situation, there's nothing that forces you to be the only person sitting with the Torah the whole time. You can always ask for someone else to hold it in the middle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a health question, not a Judaism question.

Comment: You can wear a tallit and ue it to cushion your shoulder, or you can put the torah between your legs, resting on the seat.

Comment: @sabbahillel It's definitely about Jewish Life. Judaism is more than halacha and parshanut. See the entire [tag:how-to] tag.

Comment: @Scimonster While it is Jewish Life, I think that a health source would be more useful. Perhaps health.stackexchange.com might be better, though I am not familiar with that site.

Comment: @sabbahillel At the same time, just being on-topic on [health.se] doesn't make it off-topic here.

Comment: @sabbahillel A generic health community would be nearly useless for answering this question, which requires understanding of the shape and size of a sefer Torah as well as the circumstances in which one is required to hold one, and the constraints that apply. Yes, you could write that all up in sufficient detail to make for an answerable question by generic ergonomics experts, but it makes a great deal more sense to ask somewhere where there are likely to be people with a great deal of practical experience with this particular task - here.

Comment: I think it's common practice, out of respect, not to sit on a seat when holy books are on the same seat. Not sure whether that's required, nor whether it applies to _atze chayim_ also. CYLOR.

Comment: @msh210 ooh I didn't even put that together.  It could also be that it doesn't apply if the whole reason you're sitting there is to hold the Sefer Torah.

Answer (score 5):

This probably depends in part on the size (*eitz* to *eitz* length, I mean) and weight of the *sefer torah*, but here's what people in my minyan do (and what I do personally) with a medium-sized scroll.  My description is for a left-handed person, but you can reverse it.

Sit with your back against the back of the chair.  Place your left hand in front of you and under the "disks" at the bottom end of the *eitz*, so you're supporting weight without being poked.  Let the weight of the *sefer* lean against your left shoulder.  The *sefer* is not vertical; it's leaning against your shoulder, bottom out a bit.  (It's also slightly slanted across your body.)  For our scroll this does not result in an *eitz* poking you in the thigh; the distance between you hand under the disk and the end of the eitz is short enough that the *eitzim* themselves don't rest on anything.  If you need more stability, place your right hand on the front near the center.

Sitting like this, it's easy to shift from left to right -- start by replacing the bottom hand, then slide your now-free left hand up to the middle of the scroll and shift the scroll from your left shoulder to your right.  (This does assume that you don't have a book in your free hand at the time.)

If you have any special medical conditions that affect your ability to bear weight in certain places, you should of course consult your local physician.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I'll hold off on accepting until I get a chance to try it out (which I don't think can happen any sooner than Rosh Hashana).